# Regular expression to eliminate a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var chain = "providerId=12$familyId=123&brandId=1122112$officeId=21&";
```

I need to do a method that erases a certain word with regular expressions.

Example:

```
var word = "familyId";
var newChain = deleteParam(chain, word);
console.log(newChain);
```

*Result = "providerId=12$brandId=1122112$officeId=21&";*

Delete : **familyId=123&**

I tried to do the method in the following way, but it does not work:

```
function deleteParam(chain, word) {
   var exp = new RegExp(param, "=[0-9]&");
   var str = chain.replace(exp, ""); // Delete
   return str
}
```

Please, I need your help, I can not make this method work, because I do not understand well how to build regular expressions.

Excuse me all, English is not my native language

thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this `new RegExp(param + "=\[^&]+")`

Here is an example:

```js
var chain = "providerId=12$familyId=123&brandId=1122112$officeId=21&";
var toRemove = "familyId";
var pattern = new RegExp(toRemove + "=[^&]*&");
var newChain = chain.replace(pattern, "");
console.log(newChain);
```

If you're looking to process a `GET` request's search parameters is better to use a pattern like this `(&|\?)*parameterName=[^&]*`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it has worked satisfactorily. But please could you explain me better the commented to the last, with the get request, it is very interesting.

Comment: @HenryGuillen17 I'm not sure what you're trying to do but the string you want to process looks similar to a HTTP GET request query. If that is the case, use the regex at the end of my answer because it is better (doesn't leave extra `&` or `?` characters in the resulting string).

Comment: I really needed the above function to eliminate a get parameter and it is already solved, but I found interesting below to see another way of doing things. However, thank you very much, now I can sleep peacefully